# php mysql IN search rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code

```
$sql="select * from movieTrivia WHERE id IN ('9,2,1,4,7')";
$array = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    // If the query was sucsessfull, we can get the rows
    while ($row= $result->fetch_array()) {
    $array[] = $row;

}
} else {
    // If the query failed, do something here
}
   $a               = $row['title']; 
    $b                  = $row[1]['title'];  //out put second id in array (2)?
    $c                  = $row['title']; 
    $d                  = $row['title']; 
echo json_encode(array("a" => $a, "b" => $b, "c" => $c, "d" => $d, "answerImg" => $answerImg));
```

Out Put is:
    $a = title1
    $b = null
    $c = title1
    $d = title1

It only pulls the title from the first ID in the IN array (9). How do i pull the title of 2, 1, 4 and 7

Comment: try with $sql="select * from movieTrivia WHERE `id` IN (9,2,1,4,7)";

Comment: Your fetch is not returning a multidimensional array. `$a`, `,$c`, and `$d` will all have the same values. You overwrite on every iteration.

Comment: OKay, as i suspected, how do i put the data from (9,2,1,4,7)  into an array I can access as i can above?

Answer (score 1):

you dont need quotes inside the **IN** brackets

```
$sql="select * from movieTrivia WHERE `id` IN (9,2,1,4,7)";
```

Comment: Thanks, i made the change